# Apply widget to current and future page elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

Update : I had to change the text to explain my exact problem.

I have a 3th party library for tooltips.
It works like this

jQuery("a").tooltip();

How can I attach this to all future "a" elements added using ajax on this page ?

Comment: maybe I've missed something here, but why can't you just give the elements in question a specific class and use the class to style them with CSS?

Comment: This is usually done by defining a class and applying the class to an element. Changing classes during runtime is possible but complex

Comment: what is problem with `live`??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I attach this to all future "a" elements added using ajax on this page ?

Just call:

```
jQuery("a").tooltip();
```

again in each AJAX call's `.success()` handler.

If the plugin is written properly it'll ignore any links that have already had this applied to them.  Otherwise, you'll need to change the selector so that it only picks the ones added by the AJAX call.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways:

1. Give all dynamic future elements a certain class (like `dynamic`) and use a CSS rule like this.

   ```
   span.dynamic { display: block; }
   ```
2. Make sure all dynamic elements have a certain parent element in the page (or at least a parent element with a certain class:

   ```
   #dynamicParent span { display: block; }    <-- Select single element by ID
   div.dynamicParent span { display: block; } <-- all divs with this class
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("head").append("<link>");
   css = $("head").children(":last");
   css.attr({
     rel:  "stylesheet",
     type: "text/css",
     href: "link_that_point_to_the_css"
   });
```